# Pointer events: none, filter, works in ie8 and anywhere, not ie9

Tags: css

[As I have seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements/4839672#4839672), a filter can be used to simulate a cross browser version of

```css
pointer-events: none;
```

However, this just doesn't work in IE9, nor does it in the "emulate IE8" version in IE9. A native installation of IE8 handles it fine, however. Is there any solution that makes it work for IE9?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right - AlphaImageLoader filter has been removed from IE9. <strike>This was done so that it doesn't conflict with the standards compliant methods. In this case, `pointer-events: none`, which [now works in IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).</strike>

If you're using a conditional comments to target IE for the filter fix, change them to target only IE8 and below. Try changing `<!--[if IE]>` to `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`

**Edit:** I've since come across this again and it appears that `pointer-events: none` does not work in IE9 (not for HTML elements anyway). I thought this was working, but on re-testing neither method works for click-through on IE9. Perhaps I had my IE9 in a compatibility mode.

It's not ideal at all, but you could force IE9 into IE8 mode via the `<meta>` tag switch:

```
 <!--[if ie 9]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"><![endif]-->
```

Apologies for the misinformation, I'll keep looking into this.

**Update Sept 24 2012:**

The wonderfully useful [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) has more information on `pointer-events` for HTML. Support in IE10 is still unknown and it appears that Opera does not support this property either. I would advise against using `pointer-events` for now unless you're specifically targeting Webkit/Mozilla.

Comment: Did this work? I can't seem to get it working in IE9. The docs say something about SVG but it's not exactly clear if it will work for other elements. I have .wrapper{ pointer-events:none;} .wrapper *{pointer-events:all;} and all the styles trace out in developer toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

pointer-events only works in webkit, mozilla browsers in html.

However pointer-events works on svg elements in internet explorer.

There is a good modernizr plugin https://github.com/ausi/Feature-detection-technique-for-pointer-events/blob/master/modernizr-pointerevents.min.js to test the existence of pointer-events

If you are using the pointer events to just add some sort of texture over the top you can replace a div with a svg element

```
if( !Modernizr.pointerevents )
{
    $('#texture').replaceWith('<svg id="texture"/>');
}
```